# Populate Google Calendar in JSP with Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, google-calendar-api

I have an Order Management System that offers for the user to see the orders he/she has added to a MySQL database with a Google Calendar. I am unsure how to do this or if I even can. The tutorial from Google Calendar API seems not to cover what I am trying to do. I am new to Google Calendar API and have trouble understanding how to use it the way I want to. Any advice on how I would populate the calendar on my JSP page with a servlet would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The orders are persisted on a mySQL DB that you'll then use to `create` the `Event`s to the user's account?

Comment: Correct, and I would like to do so using servlets. I have a JSP application that is used to input orders for a cake business and view them in various ways (table, calendar, etc). I persist the orders in MySQL and display them using servlets and JSTL. I have done so with a table and Google Charts but am unsure how to with Google Calendar.